# How to avoid error 429 (Too Many Requests) python with Asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, http-status-code-429

I am using the following code to make requests with aiohttp client. The server that I am trying to send request has a 30k request limit per hour per IP. So I am getting 429 too many request error. I want to put the job on sleep whenever it hits the limit.

I can extract the x_rateLimit_reset from the header so I thought I could use it to put the job on sleep but I observed very strange behavior. Sometimes the job the sleep time becomes negative and sometimes it gets stuck in sleeping mode.

For example, the last time that I ran the job, it first slept for 2000 seconds and then after the time passed, it again tried to sleep for another 2500 seconds and got stuck in sleeping mode. I think maybe the other parallel processes caused the issue so was wondering how to deal with too many request error msg when using Asyncio.

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, (asyncio.TimeoutError, aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError,TooManyRequests),
                          max_time=300)
    async def fetch(self, url, session, params):
        try:
            async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
                now = int(time.time())
                print(response)
                output = await response.read()
                output = json.loads(output)

                if 'X-RateLimit-Remaining' in response.headers:
                    rate = response.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining']

                if 'status' in output and output['status'] == 429:
                    x_rateLimit_reset = int(response.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'])
                    print("sleep mode")
                    seconds = x_rateLimit_reset - now
                    LOGGER.info("The job will sleep for {} seconds".format(seconds))
                    time.sleep(max(seconds,0))
                    raise TooManyRequests()



            return output

        except (asyncio.TimeoutError, TypeError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError,
                aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError) as e:
            print(str(e))

    async def bound_fetch(self, sem, url, session, params):
        # Getter function with semaphore.
        async with sem:
            output = await self.fetch(url, session, params)
        return {"url": url, "output": output}
```

Edited:
This is how I initiate bound_fetch and define the URLs:

```
def get_responses(self, urls, office_token, params=None):   
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(self.run(office_token, urls, params))
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(future)
    return responses

async def run(self, office_token, urls, params):
        tasks = []
        # create instance of Semaphore
        sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(200)
        timeout = ClientTimeout(total=1000)

        async with ClientSession(auth=BasicAuth(office_token, password=' '), timeout=timeout,
                                 connector=TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
            for url in urls:
                # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.bound_fetch(sem, url, session, params))
                tasks.append(task)

            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return responses

urls = [
                        "{}/{}".format(self.base_url, "{}?page={}&api_key={}".format(object_name, page_number, self.api_keys))
                        for page_number in range(batch * chunk_size + 1, chunk_size * (1 + batch) + 1)]
```

Comment: Please show code where you define a list of urls and initiate `bound_fetch`

Comment: Please see edited section

Comment: Please see edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main reason you are using `time.sleep()` instead `await asyncio.sleep()`.

**UPDATE**

Here is minimal working solution and some comment how it works.

Please use it to adopt your solution.

Take a look on [asyncio-throttle](https://github.com/hallazzang/asyncio-throttle)

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime


async def fetch(session, task):  # fetching urls and mark result of execution
    async with session.get(task['url']) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            # response.raise_for_status()
            # Here you need to somehow  handle 429 code if it acquired
            # In my example I just skip it.
            task['result'] = response.status
            task['status'] = 'done'
        await response.text()  # just to be sure we acquire data
        print(f"{str(datetime.now())}: Got result of {task['url']}")  # logging
        task['result'] = response.status
        task['status'] = 'done'


async def fetch_all(session, urls, persecond):
    # convert to list of dicts
    url_tasks = [{'url': i, 'result': None, 'status': 'new'} for i in urls]
    n = 0  # counter
    while True:
        # calc how many tasks are fetching right now
        running_tasks = len([i for i in url_tasks if i['status'] in ['fetch']])
        # calc how many tasks are still need to be executed
        is_tasks_to_wait = len([i for i in url_tasks if i['status'] != 'done'])
        # check we are not in the end of list n < len()
        # check we have room for one more task
        if n < len(url_tasks) and running_tasks < persecond:
            url_tasks[n]['status'] = 'fetch'
            #
            # Here is main trick
            # If you schedule task inside running loop
            # it will start to execute sync code until find some await
            #
            asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url_tasks[n]))
            n += 1
            print(f'Schedule tasks {n}. '
                  f'Running {running_tasks} '
                  f'Remain {is_tasks_to_wait}')
        # Check persecond constrain and wait a sec (or period)
        if running_tasks >= persecond:
            print('Throttling')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        #
        # Here is another main trick
        # To keep asyncio.run (or loop.run_until_complete) executing
        # we need to wait a little than check that all tasks are done and
        # wait and so on
        if is_tasks_to_wait != 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # wait all tasks done
        else:
            # All tasks done
            break
    return url_tasks


async def main():
    urls = ['http://google.com/?1',
            'http://google.com/?2',
            'http://google.com/?3']*3
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        res = await fetch_all(session, urls, 3)
        print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    # (asyncio.run) do cancel all pending tasks (we do not have them,
    #  because we check all task done)
    # (asyncio.run) do await canceling all tasks
    # (asyncio.run) do stop loop
    # exit program
```

Comment: Any idea how to handle 429 code? Can we queue the 429 URLs and re-send them?

Comment: Easily, its strong point of async. So there are no needs to serialise data and all variables are accessible. Additionally, you will not face with race condition in general case. In my example in `fetch` function just set status for task as 'new' after we receive `!=200` condition. This task will reschedule in main while in fetch_all function.